# Cross-correlation (time-lagged correlation) for binary variables

Tags: time-series, correlation, binary-data, cross-correlation

I am looking at two time-series, one is continuous and somewhat stationary, and the other one is very sparse with lots of 0's and a few 1's. Does the traditional Cross-correlation function still work in this case?

Comment: There is some literature:  https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9892.2007.00537.x